# Zero Coverage for controller class

Tags: visualforce, controller

I have a simple visualforce page that is meant to give a location for admins to disable a trigger and schedule a batch. I have not been able to get any test coverage when I run the test. I've ran the same tests in a developer org as part of a package and got 100% coverage. I added it to another orgs sandbox to push it up to production, and when I run the test I don't even get a response that a test has been ran. Any ideas what is missing?

Controller

```
public class CMRulesController {

public CM_Rule_Settings__c sett {get; set;}  
public CM_Rule_Triggers__c settTrig {get; set;}  

public CMRulesController(){
    this.sett = CM_Rule_Settings__c.getOrgDefaults();
    this.settTrig = CM_Rule_Triggers__c.getOrgDefaults();
}

public PageReference saveSett() {
    //update sett;
    CM_Rule_Settings__c settOld = CM_Rule_Settings__c.getOrgDefaults();

    upsert sett;
    // upsert settTrig;
    return Page.CMRulesSettings;
}

// schedules hourly batch job for CM Rules
public void scheduleCMRules(){
    CMRuleBatch batchable = new CMRuleBatch();
    String CRONSTRING = '0 0 * * * ?';
    System.schedule('CM RULE BATCH_'+System.today(), CRONSTRING ,batchable);
 }    
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
public with sharing class TestCMRulesController {

public static testMethod void settingsTest(){

    CM_Rule_Triggers__c settTrig = new CM_Rule_Triggers__c();
    settTrig.name = 'Trigger Setting';
    settTrig.Enable_Email_Summary_Rollups__c = TRUE;
    insert settTrig;

    CM_Rule_Settings__c sett = new CM_Rule_Settings__c();
    sett.Name = 'CM Rule Configuration';
    sett.Batch_Size__c = 35;
    sett.Last_Run_Batch_Date_Time__c = datetime.parse('10/6/2019 12:00 AM');
    insert sett;

    CMRulesController cmr = new CMRulesController();  

    test.startTest();
    cmr.SaveSett();
    cmr.scheduleCMRules();

    List<CM_Rule_Settings__c> t = CM_Rule_Settings__c.getAll().values();
    boolean bSize = null;
    if(t[0].Batch_Size__c == 35){
        bSize = true;
    }
    system.assertEquals(bSize, True);

    test.stopTest();
 }    
}
```

Comment: I have a hard time seeing how, assuming this test passes, it yields _zero_ coverage. Could you [edit] to confirm or clarify?

Comment: The issue does not seem to be with your code but with the process you're using to run the test. Without more detail, I don't think we can help you.

Comment: Agreed, I would go to the developer console and double check there and see what is going on because if your IDE is the one running the test, it is likely encountering some trouble with that Sandbox.

Comment: Thanks.  The class in Salesforce shows 100% coverage. But if I run the test in the dev console or try to deploy it I get no coverage.

Comment: Does the test *pass*? What, *exactly*, do you get when you review the logs and the test panel in Developer Console?